# Clearing a custom struct

Tags: solidity, mapping

What's the best way to clear a mapping? Consider the following case:

```
struct user {
    string name;
    uint id;
    bool valid;
    bytes32 hash_id;
}

mapping (address => user) userRegister;

function clearStruct (address addr) constant returns (bool cleared) {  
   userRegister[addr].name = null;  
   userRegister[addr].id = null;  
   userRegister[addr].valid = null;  
   userRegister[addr].hash_id = null; 
}
```

I am looking for a generic way to clear structs. the error i see right now at `= null`:

> Error: Expected primary expression

Anyone who could suggest, it would be greatly helpful. is the only way to make them corresponding nulls i.e. `''` for `string`, 0x000... for `bytes32`, `false` for `bool`, and `0` for `int` and so on?

Answer (score 4):

you could use `delete` to clear your map.

```
delete userRegister[addr];
```

proposition :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract test {

struct user {
    string name;
    address add;
}

mapping (address => user) public userRegister;

 function add_user (string name, address addr)   {  
     userRegister[addr].name=name;  
      userRegister[addr].add=addr;  
}


function clearStruct (address addr)   {  
   delete userRegister[addr];  

}

function try_it (address addr)  returns (string name) {  

   return userRegister[addr].name ;
}
}
```